# Errors while starting wso2as server

Tags: wso2

TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:11,101] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig} -  Failed to process JAR found at URL [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/wso2as-5.2.1_101201
    4/wso2as-5.2.1/repository/components/plugins/arq_1.0.0.wso2v1.jar!/] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/] {org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig
    TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:11,122] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig} -  Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s) {org.apache.cat
    TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:12,162]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined {org.
    TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:12,222] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext} -  Context [/] startup failed due to previous errors {org.apache.catalina.core.St
    TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:14,330]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 93ms {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.j
    TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:14,376]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Connected to mount at mounted_registry in 4ms {org.wso2.carb
    TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:15,120]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Connected to mount at mounted_registry in 3ms {org.wso2.carb
    TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:15,202]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE {org.wso2.carbon.regi
    TID: [0] [AS] [2014-01-03 04:23:18,254]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully. {org.
    wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent}

Comment: Have you tried unpacking and re-installing again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems arq_1.0.0.wso2v1.jar  is corrupted. try replacing the jar again

Comment: How can I install a new package if required because while deploying any service i could see this error is displayed at times so for this I believe i need to start with a new package.. How can i do that ?